# Edit .docx and xslx files from Express and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, heroku

I have a web application, which uses excel and word files to generate documentation, these files are stored on a local server, which is found on all network computers as a shared folder, at the time of deployment the application locally everything works correctly, but when I deploy it to a server in the cloud it stops working, the server tells me that it cannot find the excel and word files, according to me, it is because it is looking for the files in the same server in the cloud and not in the shared folder where they are stored.

Do you have any idea how I can fix this?

I share the code

Controller:

req.body.BD is equals to "K:/Compartida/INGRESOS/pr.xlsx"

```
const xlsx = require('xlsx');
const ExcelJS = require('exceljs');
const controlador = {};

controlador.Add = async (req, res) => {
//Here I receive the information of the front and save it in the excel file
    const wb = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
    wb.xlsx.readFile(req.body.BD)
        .then(() => {
            const ws = wb.getWorksheet(req.body.SheetName);
            ws.addRow(req.body.datos);
            wb.xlsx.writeFile(req.body.BD).then(() => {
                res.status(200).json({ Message: "Guardado exitoso" });
            });
        }).
        catch((error) => {
            res.status(500).json({ Message: "Ocurrio un error", error });
        });
};

controlador.Edit = async (req, res) => {

    const wb = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
    wb.xlsx.readFile(req.body.BD)
        .then(() => {
            const ws = wb.getWorksheet(req.body.SheetName);
            ws.eachRow((data) => {
                for (let j = 0; j < req.body.datos.length; j++) {
                    if (data.getCell(1).value === req.body.datos[j][0]) {
                        for (let i = 2; i <= data.cellCount; i++) {
                            data.getCell(i).value = req.body.datos[j][i - 1];
                        };
                    };
                };
            });

            wb.xlsx.writeFile(req.body.BD);
            res.status(200).json({ Message: "Guardado exitoso" });
        }).catch((error) => {
            res.status(500).json({ Message: "Ocurrio un error", error });
        });
};

controlador.GetAll = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const wb = xlsx.readFile(req.body.BD, { cellDates: true, sheetRows: false });
        const ws = wb.Sheets[req.body.SheetName];
        const data = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);

        res.status(200).json({ data });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ Message: "Ocurrio un error", error });
    };
};

module.exports = controlador;
```

Comment: 1. Don't point to local server, point to local file and commit that file. Or: 2. Make project cloud compatible: Host the file in cloud and make sure the project is cloud combatible. Or 3: Make your local server available to the internet and network mount it on your VPS. Or 4: ....

Comment: How can I point directly to the file?

I get it from a req.body.BD which is equal to "K:/Shared/INCOME/pr.xlsx"

Comment: The solution to this can be manyfold. And it is impossible to help you there. You need to decide on a solution and attempt that and share what problems you are running into. SSH into your VPS and think about a solution how to access that file. You can have a duplicate copy, network mount it, host the file somewhere else, etc.